# Content-type: text/xml returns null responseXML though responseText returns valid

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax, content-type

The PHP Code:

```
<?php

include('SQLparseQuery.php');
include('queryToXML.php');
$rows = array('code', 'name', 'price', 'description');
$filter = array("", "featured='1'");
$coffeeList = getFromSQL('*', 'coffees', $rows, $params=$filter); //Retrieves only featured coffees from SQL
makeXML($coffeeList, $rows, "coffee", "featuredCoffees", true); //writes featuredCoffees.xml

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo file_get_contents("../xml/featuredCoffees.xml");

?>
```

The Ajax call:

```
function featuredInteraction() {
        if (request.readyState==4) {
                if (request.status==200) {
                        alert(request.responseXML);
                }
        }
}
```

[A link to the XML document.](http://www.blanchardscoffee.com/xml/featuredCoffees.xml)

request.responseXML returns Null.
request.responseText returns the XML.

Everything I've found says the problem is that the: header("Content-type: text/xml"); is missing, but it's not. It's right there. The XML doc renders correctly in the browser if I go to it directly.

I have no idea what the issue is. Help would be really awesome.

**EDIT: I suppose I should add that I have a similar script which works without flaw on the site. Why this one is being cruel and unusual is completely beyond me.**

Comment: Have you verified with some client-side tool that your "Content-type" header is *really* in the HTTP response header?

Comment: Look at the one that works, and compare the differences. Seems like a very basic and easy debugging step, to me.

Comment: I used another one that I wrote on the same site which works as a base. There are no differences except the xml document name.

Comment: The Chrome "Network" developer tab will show you HTTP requests, as will the Firebug or Tamper Data plugins for Firefox.

Comment: @Tom: That obviously cannot be the case. You are missing something.

Comment: @Pointy: It shows the script (php_getFeatured.php) as returning with text/xml.. blanchardscoffee.com/shop.php if you want to check it out.

Comment: be sure that there is no output inside the php-script before sending the header. `error_reporting(E_ALL)` should force a notice if there is any ouput before)

Comment: @Dr.Molle - with that enabled, it does give an error stating that the XML declaration had to come at the start of the document. I moved the header() line to the first line, but it keeps giving me the same error. Getting there. thanks for that.

Comment: Okay. I commented everything except the header() and the echo, and it works. Clearly something in one of the includes is giving output someplace. At least the output works for now. Thanks for the help. DrM & Pointy.

Comment: GOT. IT. The problem was that in my SQL connection I was doing "mysql_query('use foobar')" instead of $foo = mysql_query(...). So it was connecting to the database without error, but because I didn't set it to a variable there was output of some sort before calling the XML doc.